# How to display data of firestore collection's documents in html after using get()

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

```
this.afs.collection('users')
.doc(this.userId)
.collection('attendance')
.get().subscribe(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

      console.log(doc.id, " => ",doc.data());
```

I want to display data of attendance collection using html, how to display it?

Comment: use html tables or any js data grid.

Comment: will you elaborate more,which helps me to understand easily. @SandeepKumar

Comment: Since you are using Angular, I suggest, go with Material Designs: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: ok i will check it...thanks for help @SandeepKumar